# How to get the information like classes inside a dll file?

Tags: powershell

I have a .net framework dll file, and it has some classes.

I want to use powershell to get all the classes' name inside the .dll file, how can I do?

update:

when I tried using `import-module "xxxxx"`, it has the following error.

[image]

Comment: A great tool for snooping assemblies is [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).

Comment: @vonPryz, is there any way import all the related module/dll in one step? I just want to use ps code without other tools.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, I just want to use ps code to import all the related dll/module in one step. I know I can find all the dependency module, and import them one by one. But just want to import them in one step.

Comment: @IvanYang Sorry, I do not know

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do:

```
$Assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('c:\temp\file.dll')
$Assembly.DefinedTypes
$Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
$Assembly.GetLoadedModules()
```

Comment: Consider using `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\temp\file.dll")` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I get: `MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform."` using that.

Comment: To see all supported methods, use: `[System.Reflection.Assembly] | Get-Member -Static`

Comment: The [ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom?view=net-7.0) method is now obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Another a way: import the DLL with `Import-Module` and call assembly's `GetTypes()`. Like so,

```
import-module '<your_path>\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
$smo = ([appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) | 
    where {$_.modules.name.contains('SqlServer')}
$smo.gettypes() | where {$_.isPublic -and $_.isClass}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This dll I tried to import has some dependency dlls, so when use import-module, it will give an error, you can see my updated question.